# ¿Hay un equivalente a cin.clear() y cin.ignore() en Java?

Tags: java, c++, netbeans, poo

Tengo un metodo que me sirve para validar variables `int`, pero al pasarlas de *C++* a *Java* no me sirven los métodos `ignore` y `clear`.

¿Existe algún equivalente a esas funciones en *Java*?

```
int ValidaInt(){

    int numero;

    if (cin>>numero)
    {
        return numero;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"El caracter digitado no corresponde a un numero\n";
        cout<<"Por favor digite un numero:\n";
        cin.clear(256,"\n");
        cin.ignore();
        validaInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

para validar la entrada de un numero en java seria algo así:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero;
    do {
        System.out.println("Dame un numero");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Te dije un numero");
            sc.next(); //esperar el siguiente input
        }
            numero= sc.nextInt();
    } while (numero<= 0);
  System.out.println(numero);
```

Comment: @KevinMendez La forma que le dicen en esta respuesta quizas sea lo que busca. Pero si lo que quiere es una equivalencia quizas busque `public Scanner skip(Pattern pattern)`,  y `public Scanner reset()`. Pero en Java puede usar algo asi `String uno = sc.next(), dos = sc.next(); System.out.println(uno +" " + dos);` para capturar una cadena o entrada similar a esta "tiene un espacio"-> "`123 123`". Saludos